# Firebase security rule does not prevent removeValue()

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have set the security rule the following, but the `.removeValue()` is still able to delete records. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && newData.exists()"
  }
}
```

Here is the code (in swift) that attempts to remove an entry and according to the security rules should fail, but it succeeds:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "myDatabase/customerIDs")
ref.child("\(customerID)").child(scheduleIDs[indexPath.row]).removeValue()
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the call that success that you think should be rejected? Btw: I'd normally expect the `newData.exists()` in a `.validate` rule, but I don't think it makes a difference here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the client code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code removes a single value from `/myDatabase/customerIDs/$customerId/$scheduleId`. Your rules only reject writes that delete the entire database, not writes that delete a single schedule ID. If you want to disallow those, add a rule on the correct path too.

Something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "myDatabase": {
      "customerIDs": {
        "$customerId": {
          "$scheduleId": {
            ".validate": "newData.exists()"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does your rule above also prevent the entire database to be deleted? I want such protection as well.